# How do I retrive data from sub chield table in my Spring Boot Project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, hibernate-onetomany

I have two entity "User" and "UserOtp" which have a relation as One to Many. I want to show them in one table where my user all fields will show and only one field will be from "UserOtp". Following is the details code.

"User"

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "userid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int userid;
    private String msisdn;
    private String userPin;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "iduser_role")
    private UserRole roleId;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ud_id")
    private DeviceProfile deviceProfile;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pp_id")
    private PersonalProfile personalProfile;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pa_id")
    private PersonalAccount personalAccount;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid")
    List<UserOtp> userOtp;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    private int status;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date createDate;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date updateDate;
    
    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(String msisdn, String userPin, UserRole roleId, DeviceProfile deviceProfile,
            PersonalProfile personalProfile, PersonalAccount personalAccount, List<UserOtp> userOtp, int status,
            Date createDate, Date updateDate) {
        super();
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
        this.userPin = userPin;
        this.roleId = roleId;
        this.deviceProfile = deviceProfile;
        this.personalProfile = personalProfile;
        this.personalAccount = personalAccount;
        this.userOtp = userOtp;
        this.status = status;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

--- Getter and Setter ---
```

"UserOTP"

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_otp")
public class UserOtp {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "iduser_otp")
    private int iduserOtp;
    private String otp;
    private Date createDate;
    private Date updateDate;
    private int status;
    
    public UserOtp() {
    }

    public UserOtp(String otp, Date createDate, Date updateDate, int status) {
        super();
        this.otp = otp;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
        this.status = status;
    }

------ Getter and Setter -----
```

"Controller"

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/index")
    public String Login(Model model) {
        
        long countUsers = userRepositoryService.countUsers();
        
        Users user = userRepositoryService.getUsers(1);
        
        List<Users> users = userRepositoryService.getUsers();
        
        model.addAttribute("usersCount", countUsers);
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        
        System.out.println(user.getUserOtp().toString());
        
        return "/admin/index";
    }
```

Thymeleaf Page

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                            <th>OTP</th>
                            <th>Gen. Time</th>
                            <th>Update Time</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr class="odd gradeX" th:each="user : ${users}">
                            <td th:text="${user.userid}">01</td>
                            <td th:text="${user.msisdn}">01791631664</td>
                            <td th:text="${user.userOtp}">6566</td>
                            <td th:text="${user.CreateDate}">July 12, 2012 12:13:00 PM</td>
                            <td th:text="${user.UpdateDate}">July 12, 2012 12:13:00 PM</td>
                            <th th:text="${user.status}">Active</th>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
```

And Output i'm getting is below:

[image]

I just want to show only the 'otp' field last data.

Comment: The actual output is missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate objects with Spring EL using the period (".") character.

So, in your case, if you would like to show only the status field, you can use:

```
    <td th:text="${user.userOtp.status}">6566</td>
```

For more information you can have a look at section 1 of the [Spring MVC & Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html) documentation to learn about Spring EL.

Also, you may find chapter 4.3.2 of the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-properties-arrays) useful as well, describing how to access nested properties, and how to use safe navigation.